# Не работает сайт на modx

Tags: php, modx

Добрый день, перестал работать сайт на modx. Сыпятся ошибки:

Warning: include_once(/home/artbronze/art-bronze.com/core/model/modx/mysql/../modsystemsetting.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/artbronze/art-bronze.com/core/model/modx/mysql/modsystemsetting.class.php on line 6

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home/artbronze/art-bronze.com/core/model/modx/mysql/../modsystemsetting.class.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear') in /home/artbronze/art-bronze.com/core/model/modx/mysql/modsystemsetting.class.php on line 6

Fatal error: Class 'modSystemSetting' not found in /home/artbronze/art-bronze.com/core/model/modx/mysql/modsystemsetting.class.php on line 11

Comment: ну так написано же, что ошибка подключения файла. проверяйте пути

Answer (score 1):

Нужно проверить пути к ядру и другим необходимым файлам. Список файлов, где править пути:

1. config.core.php (в корне сайта) - `define('MODX_CORE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/core/');`
2. manager/config.core.php - `define('MODX_CORE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__) . '/core/');`
3. connectors/config.core.php - `define('MODX_CORE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__) . '/core/');`
4. core/config/config.inc.php